# Load javascript into bottom of head

Tags: javascript

I need some help. Is there a way to use javascript to add scripts src's to the end of the head? I have some dynamic scripts that are now allowing me to put my scripts at the bottom of the head Is there a way to do this with javascript.

For example, I need these to be at the bottom of the head tag:

```
<script src="/jQuerySlider/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jQuerySlider/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure your question makes sense. The browser normally loads all the scripts that is required by the page. So dynamically creating these scripts, I am not sure if it will give you desired functionality. I am assuming your dynamic scripts you mentioned earlier are server scripts...

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by using `createElement` for creating a `<script>` element, and then using `appendChild` to append (i.e. at the bottom) the script element to the `<head>` element:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");  // a new <script>

scriptElement.setAttribute("src", "/....js");          // set src
scriptElement.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); // not mandatory in HTML5

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];   // the <head>

head.appendChild(scriptElement);                       // append, so at bottom
```